# Combine results without using intersect in SQL SERVER 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there any way that i can restructure this below query without using intersect. Because using intersect causing very slow performance. Please suggest

`SELECT DISTINCT( PFM.id ) AS PfmFolderFK 
FROM   cm.pfmfolder PFM WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap PFMMST WITH(nolock) 
               ON PFMMST.pfmfolderfk = PFM.id 
       INNER JOIN cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock) 
               ON MST.id = PFMMST.mstipfk 
WHERE  MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode 
       AND PFM.deletedby IS NULL 
       AND PFM.deleteddate IS NULL 
INTERSECT 
SELECT DISTINCT( FMAP.pfmfolderfk ) AS PfmFolderFK 
FROM   cm.mstip MIP WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap FMAP WITH(nolock) 
               ON MIP.id = FMAP.mstipfk 
                  AND MIP.registrycode = @RegistryCode 
                  AND MIP.deletedby IS NULL 
                  AND MIP.deletedate IS NULL`

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan to see if there are any improvements available to the query? Seems like a fairly simple query so maybe there are some missing/bad indexes on the tables which is forcing table scans or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

An `intersect` is taking values from both tables.  The queries are quite similar here, so I think you just need an additional join in the first table to complete the logic without an `intersect`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( PFM.id ) AS PfmFolderFK 
FROM cm.pfmfolder PFM WITH(nolock) INNER JOIN
     cm.pfmfoldermstipmap PFMMST WITH(nolock) 
     ON PFMMST.pfmfolderfk = PFM.id INNER JOIN
     cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock) 
     ON MST.id = PFMMST.mstipfk INNER JOIN
     cm.pfmfoldermstipmap FMAP WITH(nolock) 
     ON PFMMST.id = FMAP.mstipfk AND
        PFMMST.registrycode = @RegistryCode AND
        PFMMST.deletedby IS NULL  AND
        PFMMST.deletedate IS NULL
WHERE MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode AND
      PFM.deletedby IS NULL AND
      PFM.deleteddate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I think you need to take only the first part of your query and add two contitions to it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FMAP.pfmfolderfk AS PfmFolderFK
FROM cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock)
INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap FMAP WITH(nolock) ON MST.id = FMAP.mstipfk
INNER JOIN cm.pfmfolder PFM WITH(nolock) ON FMAP.pfmfolderfk = PFM.id
WHERE MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode
    AND PFM.deletedby IS NULL
    AND PFM.deleteddate IS NULL
    AND MST.deletedby IS NULL
    AND MST.deletedate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries with DISTINCT are always dubious ;-) You are looking for pfmfolders where certain records exist in pfmfoldermstipmap and mstip. Use EXISTS for that. Actually you are looking for all pfmfolders that are in pfmfoldermstipmap and mstip and are either not deleted themselves or having not deleted mstips:

```
select id 
from cm.pfmfolder
where exists
(
  select *
  from cm.pfmfoldermstipmap
  inner join cm.mstip on mstip.id = pfmfoldermstipmap.mstipfk
  and pfmfoldermstipmap.pfmfolderfk = pfmfolder.id
  and mstip.registrycode = @registrycode
  and
  (
    (pfmfolder.deletedby is null and pfmfolder.deleteddate is null)
    or
    (mstip.deletedby is null and mstip.deleteddate is null)
  )
);
```